# Stack pointer as an index register

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers, machine-code, addressing-mode

Why can't the stack pointer (esp / rsp) be used as an index register, like `[esi + esp*4]`?

Answer (score 3):

That's just how the instruction set has been made. The SIB encoding for `ESP` (which is `100b`) has been used to mean `none` instead<sup>1</sup>. Normally `ESP` is the stack pointer and as such used as base register, which does have a valid encoding. It doesn't usually make sense to scale it with any factor, so sacrificing that encoding isn't generally a problem.

---

1. See *Table 2-3. 32-Bit Addressing Forms with the SIB Byte* in the [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual Volume 2: Instruction Set Reference, A-Z](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf)